# React: Handling Events - parameter visibility

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrow-functions

I am following React Doc. In '[Handling Events](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html)' section, the below code segment is there.

```js
class Toggle extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {isToggleOn: true};

    // This binding is necessary to make `this` work in the callback
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <button onClick={this.handleClick}>
        {this.state.isToggleOn ? 'ON' : 'OFF'}
      </button>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Toggle />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

in `handleClick()` function, how `state` is available for it to access? Why not `this.state`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how this.setState works, its an updater callback passed for `this.setState()`, as per react [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html#what-is-the-difference-between-passing-an-object-or-a-function-in-setstate):

> Passing an update function allows you to access the current state
>   value inside the updater. Since setState calls are batched, this lets
>   you chain updates and ensure they build on top of each other instead
>   of conflicting

more information can be found [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) as well.

Answer (score 2):

Because it's a function parameter. In this code:

```
 handleClick() {
    this.setState(state => ({
      isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
    }));
  }
```

This part, is an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which takes previous state of the component, as a parameter:

```
state => ({
  isToggleOn: !state.isToggleOn
})
```

And returns a new state, which triggers re-render and so on.

> Why not this.state?

The rule of thumb: If your *next* state depends on *previous* state, you **must** use this approach to update your state. So you don't run into a race condition with `this.setState` calls because is asynchronous function.

Hope it helps :)